# Is there a way to get Apple sign-in working with msal as a login for Azure AD B2C?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, apple-sign-in

I've followed these instructions to set up "Sign in with Apple" as an identity provider for our Azure AD B2C user flow:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple

We currently have other logins working (Local, Microsoft, Google) with msal in our Xamarin.iOS app, however when we try to use the new Apple sign-in from the app, we get the error: **"invalid redirect_uri"** from the Apple sign-in page.

I think this is because we have only specified the following redirect when following the instructions:

`https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`

and not the one that msal uses (e.g. `msal[appId]://auth`).

However, this redirect isn't valid to enter as a domain in the **"Apple Services ID"** section of the instructions above, so I think we may need to do something different.

Is there a way to get Apple sign-in working with msal here?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible!

Comment: This is the right one: https://yourtenant.b2clogin.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp, because the Application in respect to Apple is B2C, not your iOS client. Your iOS client is the App to B2C, hence it is B2C that needs your msal:// redirect uri. Did you make sure to use b2clogin.com in your msal settings and not login.mocrosoftonline.com?

Comment: @JasSuri The link is dead. Do you have an updated URL please?

Comment: @AmirNo-Family Jas' comment isn't a link, but just saying what url format needs to be used when following the instructions in the question link. I.e. when setting up "Sign in with Apple" you'll need to specify a "redirect uri" which will be of the form in Jas' comment. You'll need to replace "yourtenant" with the name of your specific Azure B2C account